# Association Clarification Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

This is probably so simple its stupid, but I'm having a brainfreeze moment and am just staring at the screen now going nowhere.

I have two models a member and a membership, each member can have one type of membership from a selection of many.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :forename, :middlename, :surname, :house_no, :house_name, :street, :town, :postcode, :home_tel, :mobile_tel, :work_tel, :email       
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :membership_type
end
```

My membership model will have a few records pre populated so that a member can choose which type of membership they would like, ie Peak, Off Peak, Student

Am i correct in thinking that the member model will look like this

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 **has_one :membership**(added this)
 **accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership**
 attr_accessible **:membership_attributes(Added This)**, :forename, :middlename, :surname, :house_no, :house_name, :street, :town, :postcode, :home_tel, :mobile_tel, :work_tel, :email   

end
```

So i create a migration and add the membership_id column to the member model as the foreign key?

My Membership Model can look like this

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
**belongs_to :member** (Added This)
attr_accessible :membership_type    
end
```

am i looking at this correctly here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So i create a migration and add the membership_id column as the
>   foreign key?

I think that in your migration you have to add a member_id column to the memberships table, as the foreign key.

([Active Record Associations has one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association))